# Understanding Depth-First Branch and Bound implementation to StarCraft 2

Tags: python, algorithm, search, artificial-intelligence, depth-first-search

The problem is that I'm finding it difficult to understand how DFBB works, what the parameters  and output should be for this case.

I'm working on creating an AI for the game StarCraft 2 that will handle the build order in the game (for team Terran). I was planning to follow the approach described in the link (see below) which followed a very similar thing that I was going for. To summarize what I'm planning to do:

A list of different type of buildings that need to be built will be given to me. Buildings cost minerals and gas (this is the currency in the game), some buildings have prerequisites (meaning other buildings need to be built before it's possible to build it) and they take a certain amount of time to build.

In the article they used Depth-First Branch and Bound to figure out the optimal build order, meaning the fastest way possible to build the buildings in that list. This was their pseudocode:

[image: Pseudocode for DFBB]

Where the state S is represented by S = (current game time, resources available, actions in progress but not completed, worker income data). How S´ is derived is described article and it is done through three functions so that bit I understand.

As mentioned earlier I'm struggling to understand what the starting status S, goal G, time limit t and bound b should be represented by in the pseudocode that they are describing.

I only know three things for sure: the list of buildings that needs to be built, what consumables I have at the moment (minerals and gas), resources (that is buildings I already have in the game). This should then be applied to the algorithm somehow, but it is unclear what the input should be to the function. The output should be a list sorted in the right order so if I where to building the buildings in the order they come in then it should all work out and it should be the optimal possible time it can be done in.

For example should I iterate through the list buildings and run DFBB on every element with the goal then being seeing if the building can be built. But what should the time limit be set too and what does bound mean in this case? Is it simply the cost?

Please explain how this function should be run on the list in order to find the optimal path of building it. The article is fairly easy to read, but I need some help understanding how it is meant to work and how I can apply it to my problem.

Link to article: https://ai.dmi.unibas.ch/research/reading_group/churchill-buro-aiide2011.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting Status S is the initial state at the start of the game. I believe you have 100 minearls and Command center and 12? SCVs, so that's your start.

The Goal here is the list of building you want to have. The satisfies condition is are all building in goal also in S.

The time limit is the amount of time you are willing to spend to get the result. If yous set it to 5 seconds it will probably give you a sub-optimal solution, but it will do it in 5 seconds. If the algorithm finishes the search it will return earlier. If you don't care leave it out, but make sure you write solutions to a file in case something happens.

Bound b is the in-game time limit for building everything. You initially set it to infinite or some obvious value (like 10 minutes?). When you find a solution the b gets updated so every new solution you find MUST be faster (in-game) than the previous one.

A few notes. Make sure that the possible action (children in step 9) includes doing nothing (wait for more resources) and building an SCV.

Another thing that might be missing is a correct modelling of SCV movement speed. The units need to move to a place to build something and it also takes time for them to get back to mining.

Comment: Very good explanation! I only have one more thing that I don't understand then I think I got everything. How does the tree look S or how does it finds its children? For example if I have a very simple list [Factory, Bunker,Supply Depot,Barracks]. Factory and Bunker need Barracks and Barracks need Supply Depot. Assume we have everything necessary for building Supply Depot to begin with. I assume we go through the list and find we only can build Supply depot, we update it as bound and then we come to the else statement. Do I use a "pre-made" version of the tech tree to find the children?

Comment: And another question is how does S then store that we are looking for the children of a supply depot. As they described it in the article S = (current game time, resources available, actions in progress but not completed, worker income data) so I don't understand how it knows its looking for a solution for supply depot.

Comment: So S is the state (like you said, game time, resources, etc...). The "tree" in this case is implicit. The children are the possible actions (do nothing, build SCV, build Baracks, etc...) The new state that the child leads to is what happens after you take that action (i.e. if you don't do anything game time advances a bit, you have a bit more resources and the building progress moves a bit further, if you pick build a Baracks, you have one less miner and a barracks in progress with 0% completion, etc...)

Comment: Okay, I see. I have one last question. On line 11, why do they save the parent state in the new state. Where is it saved in the new state (what parameter) and why is it necessary? I'm thinking that just doing S' <-- S.nextChild should be enough. I assume they do it for some sort of backtracking but I don't understand how this would work.

Comment: @Programming_Zeus That just for constructing the solution, since it's not always obvious what the previous state was. You can also have a stack of state and take a copy of that, to save the solution. If you don't care about reconstructing the solution you can skip it entirely.